# Does the federal government of USA have any powers over functioning of ICANN

Tags: united-states, internet, international

Since the very inception of the internet, as we know it today, USA had a pivotal role to play including in the management of DNS (Domain Name System). However internet evolved to be more free.

However, ICANN (Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers) — the body governing DNS — is of US origin.

*Does the federal government of USA still have any powers over functioning of ICANN?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The U.S. government previously contracted with ICANN for services, and that contract gave the Department of Commerce oversight authority over ICANN.

But both that contract and the department's oversight responsibilities [ended in 2016](https://www.icann.org/en/announcements/details/stewardship-of-iana-functions-transitions-to-global-internet-community-as-contract-with-us-government-ends-1-10-2016-en), making ICANN a fully private entity. At this point, the federal government's relationship with ICANN is more like its relationship with any other private company or individual; it can write laws and regulations governing its behavior, but it may not exert direct control over its actions.

Comment: As a practical matter, one might note that the US benefits from having ICANN based in the US and from having a global internet, and heavy-handed enforcement against ICANN might cause the *global* internet to splinter into various competing parts as regions set up their independent DNS servers.

Comment: @o.m. - Strictly speaking, DNS servers aren't that big a deal - it's extremely likely that each country/region maintains its own servers for their own region domain anyways (`.us`, `.in`, etc).  It's also not uncommon for ISPs to run their own DNS servers (often to serve ads for pages that don't exist).  And having your own DNS server is trivial to get around, too... so long as no other steps are taken to shape network traffic (like preventing routes to outside the country, a la the great firewall).

Comment: I think what o.m. means is if the global internet splintered into competing parts such that independent DNS servers didn't consider names allocated by each other to be authoritative. The problem is not great firewalls, it's if there are three different supposed-authorities each claiming a different IP address for `stackexchange.com` or some other domain.

Comment: @kaya3 well, .com is a US domain, so it would be pretty sensible in such a dispute to change it to .com.us, but keep the rest the same - as the USA should have authority over .us.

Comment: @user253751, but a DNS server in Russia could assign the IP of stackexchange.com.us to kremlin.ru, and everything would come apart.

Comment: @o.m. just like it currently redirects certain media sites to a "this anti-state propaganda is blocked" page

Comment: @user253751, there is difference between a placeholder and giving that address to a domestic user who can use it. Who gets to keep the IP when the nets are united again?

Comment: @o.m - Sure, but directing to a different IP is only a minor speed bump if they don't also block/redirect other DNS traffic - ie, they have to block the google and cloudflare DNS services (and any number of other ones).

Comment: @o.m. obviously the US gets to keep everything under .us and Russia gets to keep everything under .ru. We are not talking about IP addresses here

Comment: @user253751, that would require the two to cooperate on assigning IPs, but not on assigning domain names.

Comment: @o.m. it's almost like IPs and domain names are administered by different organizations

Comment: @user253751, the DNS is about matching the two.

Comment: ...and........?